# Can a router resolve be set as a function of a controller class?

Tags: angularjs

**Background**

I've been reading Todd Motto's opinionated style guide, in particular the part relating to Router resolves - scroll down to the '*Controller.resolve property:*' part:

https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#routing-resolves

I've always disliked the fact that i had resolve logic defined in my router definition, so in theory quite liked this solution, but in practice, i don't see how it's possible?

Todd states:

> 'This keeps resolve dependencies inside the same file as the Controller and the router free from logic'

So my understanding of this - using his example - is that you'd have your controller logic in one file (for arguments sake controllers.js) defined as,

```
app.module('myapp')
   .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl() {
    ///some controller logic here
}

MainCtrl.resolve = {
    someStuff: function() {
        //resolve something here
    }
}
```

And then in another file (routes.js) you'd have,

```
app.module('myapp')
   .config(config);

function config ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
            resolve: MainCtrl.resolve
     });
}
```

To prevent polluting the global scope, i'm presuming that both of these files logic would be within an IIFE. So the only place that `MainCtrl` would exist is as an injectable value within the angular app. And as you can't inject a controller into `config`, there's no way for it to know what `MainCtrl` is, let alone access its `resolve` method.

**Question**

Or am i missing something in the way that this should be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "IIFE scoping" piece:

*To avoid polluting the global scope with our function declarations that get passed into Angular, ensure build tasks wrap the concatenated files inside an IIFE"*

We do this at compile time, so nothing is global. We simply wrap the entire module inside an IIFE, and that's it :)

I wouldn't recommend wrapping *every* file inside an IIFE, because that's just needless function calls at runtime, if you had 1000 files for instance. One IIFE per module is also a good approach :)

Comment: Ahhhh, i'm pretty new to javascript/angular, but that crossed my mind after i'd submitted the question. Thanks Todd.

Comment: I've got gulp set up to deal with this. I'm concatenating and wrapping each module, then concatenating the entire app into one build.js file for dev. Am i right in thinking that you'd develop against this file (load it into your browser to view/test changes), not the src, to ensure there are no scoping issues or global scope polution? Would you also test against this file for the same reason? Or test against your src?